# Можно ли в C# считать класс объектом?

Tags: c#, классы, объекты

Можно ли в C# считать класс объектом? Ведь у него же есть методы, свойства (public переменные)?

Comment: Надеюсь, я своей правкой не сломал вопрос и речь только о C#, а не об ООП вообще. Потому что в последнем случае ответ был бы на порядок веселее.

Comment: Если речь не о Delphi.NET, то нет :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Класс = тип, т.е. некоторое "описание", метаданные. Класс всегда один. Это рецепт торта, если хотите.

Объект = экземпляр типа, т.е. "физическое" воплощение описания. Объектов может быть много. Это выпеченный по рецепту торт. Если говорить о реализации -- это участок памяти, содержащий служебные данные плюс данные самого объекта.

При этом CLR естественно где-то нужно хранить информацию о типе, о том, по какому адресу вызвать методы типа, знать, какой объект к какому типу относится, и т.д. Для этого есть объект-тип (type object) -- расположенная в памяти информация о типе, на которую ссылаются все экземпляры этого типа (с помощью type object pointer в секции служебных данных). Подробнее об этом можно почитать в книге Джеффри Рихтера "CLR via C#", глава 4.

Однако даже несмотря на это, называть класс объектом будет некорректно. Вас банально не поймут другие разработчики.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение :)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy не за что. Читайте и перечитывайте Рихтера -- зачтется.

Comment: хорошо, будем читать :D

Answer (score 5):

Класс - это класс (не объект). Экземпляр класса (созданный через оператор `new`) - это объект.

Comment: Возможно лучше сказать "экземпляр класса - объект", а не "объект класса - объект", а то масло масляное получается.

Comment: @KromStern, поправил. Хотя в повседневности "экземпляр класса" и "объект класс" - равнозначные.